# Finding the magnetic field from magnetization

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

with distributing magnetic bipolars in vacuum, we have the magnetization:
$$\vec{M}= \frac{a}{\rho}M_{0}\hat{\phi}$$
in the region $0<a\leq\rho\leq b$  ,  $0\leq \phi<2\times\pi$ , $0\leq z\leq h$ in cylindrical coordinates.

 $M_{0}$ is a constant with the unit $[\frac{A}{m}]$. there is no magnetic bipolars in other places in space. now how can I find the magnetic field for $\rho>b$?

 I found out that curl of $M$ is 0, so we have   $\oint{\vec{B}.\vec{dl}}=\mu_{0}(\int{\int{\vec{J_{free}}.\vec{ds}}})$

 and since $$J_{free}=\vec{M}\times \vec{n} , J_{free} = -\frac{a}{b}M_{0}\vec{z}$$
 and now I'm not sure how I can continue to solve this. I've learned this lesson recently, so sorry if it's a basic question.